# Is MagicOnion incompatible with MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

I have a common library in .NET 7 that defines the interface of the service. This common library has only one interface:

```
using MagicOnion;

namespace GTS.RegistroHorario.Servicio.Grpc.MagicOnion.Comun.Interfaces;

public interface IPersonal : IService<IPersonal>
{
    UnaryResult<(string? Token, DateTime? FechaExpiracionUtc)> LoginAsync(string paramNombreusuario, string paramPassword);

    UnaryResult<long> AgregarRegistroHorarioDeEntradaAsync(double? paramLongitud, double? paramLatitud);

    UnaryResult<long> AgregarRegistroHorarioDeSalidaAsync(double? paramLongitud, double? paramLatitud);
}
```

When I include this project in a MAUI project I get this error:

> Error NETSDK1082
> There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x64'.

If I don't include it and include another library in .NET 7, for example a repository that uses Entity Framework, I don't have any problem, so I am wondering if there is some compatibility problem with magicOnion and MAUI.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to MAUI an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: Umm am i reading this incorrectly or are you trying to use a .Net Core library in Maui?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not trying to use MAUI in an ASP core application, this is the error that I get, but in my MAUI project i don't have a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, just it is new MAUI project in which I have added a reference to my common library.

Comment: Yeah but your `GTS.RegistroHorario.Servicio` project file appears to have an XML definition of `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`?

Comment: Well, I have seen that the MAUI project has a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in the frameworks dependencies, but I can't delete it', is is added by default when I create a new MAUI project (it has a lock icon). This reference is always, and it compiles if I don't add a reference to my library of MagicOnion, and if I add the reference to this project, then I have this error. I also have tried, in the library, remove any reference to the MagicOnion package. In this case, I can compile MAUI project if I have added the reference to  this library. Si I guess the problem is MagicOnion.